# QML Label Crashes App under OpenGL Core Profile

Tags: qt, opengl, qtquick2

Starting with a new QtQuick2 project, using Ubuntu 12.04 and Mac OSX.  I've tried this on Qt 5.3.1 and 5.3.2.

I use this code to create a QQuickView set to OpenGL 4.1 Core Profile

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QQuickView * m_pMainView = new QQuickView;

QSurfaceFormat f;
f.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
f.setVersion(4, 1);
m_pMainView->setFormat(f);

m_pMainView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));

m_pMainView->show();

return app.exec();
```

My QML is simple.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Rectangle {
    visible: true

    height: 800
    width: 600

    Label {
        text: "Test"
    }
}
```

Running this causes the app to seg fault immediately.  Switch the Label control in QML to a Text control, no crash.  Runs as expected.  Switch the QSurfaceFormat to an applicable compatibility profile (3.3 on Ubuntu / 2.1 on Mac), no crash.  Runs as expected.

Am I doing something horribly wrong in how I change the OpenGL version, or is Qt 5.3 just unacceptably unstable in core profile?

In case it is useful, here is a stack trace from Mac:

```
    Thread 6 Crashed:: QSGRenderThread
0   QtGui                           0x0000000101cd41a7 QOpenGLContextPrivate::maxTextureSize() + 343
1   QtGui                           0x0000000101f33907 QOpenGLTextureGlyphCache::maxTextureHeight() const + 39
2   QtGui                           0x0000000101ec4137 QTextureGlyphCache::populate(QFontEngine*, int, unsigned int const*, QFixedPoint const*) + 1687
3   QtQuick                         0x0000000100d488f0 QSGTextMaskMaterial::populate(QPointF const&, QVector<unsigned int> const&, QVector<QPointF> const&, QSGGeometry*, QRectF*, QPointF*, QMargins const&) + 432
4   QtQuick                         0x0000000100d473fd QSGDefaultGlyphNode::update() + 797
5   QtQuick                         0x0000000100dc7632 QQuickTextNode::addGlyphs(QPointF const&, QGlyphRun const&, QColor const&, QQuickText::TextStyle, QColor const&, QSGNode*) + 482
6   QtQuick                         0x0000000100dcbc61 QQuickTextNodeEngine::addToSceneGraph(QQuickTextNode*, QQuickText::TextStyle, QColor const&) + 2049
7   QtQuick                         0x0000000100dc7fbd QQuickTextNode::addTextLayout(QPointF const&, QTextLayout*, QColor const&, QQuickText::TextStyle, QColor const&, QColor const&, QColor const&, QColor const&, int, int, int, int) + 557
8   QtQuick                         0x0000000100dc5368 QQuickText::updatePaintNode(QSGNode*, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData*) + 1000
9   QtQuick                         0x0000000100d88995 QQuickWindowPrivate::updateDirtyNode(QQuickItem*) + 3317
10  QtQuick                         0x0000000100d7fdb2 QQuickWindowPrivate::syncSceneGraph() + 306
11  QtQuick                         0x0000000100d5d388 QSGRenderThread::sync() + 120
12  QtQuick                         0x0000000100d5d475 QSGRenderThread::syncAndRender() + 117
13  QtQuick                         0x0000000100d5d968 QSGRenderThread::run() + 200
14  QtCore                          0x00000001016923f2 QThreadPrivate::start(void*) + 338
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff94d23899 _pthread_body + 138
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff94d2372a _pthread_start + 137
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff94d27fc9 thread_start + 13
```

Comment: In a similar vein, applying an opacity mask against a png file under this same main.cpp / main.qml combination yields a string of fragment shader errors and no rendering, while switching back to a compatibility profile works fine.

Comment: Any chance that instead of pasting that as a mess of hard to read comments you could actually just edit your question to include the trace?

Comment: Does your graphics hardware even support OGLv4.1?

Comment: Yes, my hardware on both machines supports 4.1.  Worth noting I get the exact same results on 3.3 Core.  I've updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Also, if I add a custom openGL widget to the working version (the one with text instead of label) and print the version of my opengl context, it outputs the expected / requested version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though some members of the Qt team have stated that Qt versions 5.2 and beyond are compatible with the core profile, the reality is that Qt Controls is not slated to work until 5.4.  Here's the bug:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38817